# android firebase user login trouble with intent inside if statement

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to use IF with my login stuff.
The purpose of this is to create the user in the firebase if it does not exist, and just log in if it does exist.
The reason I want to do this, is that I want to put more info under the users UID, but this info gets erased from firebase every time the user logs in, because it always updates the UID and entries below it.

There may be another way to do this, but this is the only solution I was able to find.

The problem I am having is that when building I get an error. See error message below.

**This is in my MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onFirebaseLoggedIn(final AuthData authData) {
    // TODO: Handle successful login
    Firebase userRef= new Firebase("https://theatre-assistant.firebaseio.com/users");
    userRef.child(authData.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://theatre-assistant.firebaseio.com/");
                // Authentication just completed successfully :)
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("provider", authData.getProvider());
                if (authData.getProviderData().containsKey("displayName")) {
                    map.put("displayName", authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
                    map.put("profileImageURL", authData.getProviderData().get("profileImageURL").toString());

                }
                ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).setValue(map);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

**Error when building**

```
Users/runelangaard/AndroidStudioProjects/TheatreAssistant/app/src/main/java/com/langaard/theatreassistant/MainActivity.java:61: error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous ValueEventListener>,Class<HomeActivity>)
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                                    ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
    constructor Intent.Intent(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Intent) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Intent.Intent() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
/Users/runelangaard/AndroidStudioProjects/TheatreAssistant/app/src/main/java/com/langaard/theatreassistant/MainActivity.java:77: error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous ValueEventListener>,Class<HomeActivity>)
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                                    ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
    constructor Intent.Intent(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Intent) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Intent.Intent() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
2 errors

 FAILED
```

How can I correct this issue?

Thanks
Rune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
```

Comment: That solved the issue with the intent, thanks. Its always easier than I think. :) Now the app builds, and runs, but somehow the user never gets logged in. Any idea why?

Comment: do u get any errors while logging in? @RuneLangaard

Comment: Upvoted! No errors, it just shows the spinning circle thing, and nothing happens.

Comment: Use Log statements and see what's happening while executing

Comment: Found the problem. It was not related to this at all. I found out it worked with google login, and only facebook was not working. The problem was that i translated the app, and in the translated strings.xml file, the facebook app id did not exist.